# Couchbase Database android - Delete a row from Document

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I am having a problem with delete a specific row from Document. Prepare Database and Document Object, and save the data using document update method. In doc, there is method to delete a document but I am not getting how to delete a view/row using query. Provide me a guidance how can I achieve this.

Comment: Please show us your relevant snippet of code, where you are trying to delete a row from document and explain the problem.